# How to remove .html from Magento url

Tags: magento-1.9

I am new in Magento development, I have develop a e commerce site but my site url have .html I want to remove this
now Ex. **www.mydomainname.com/shop.html**
how can remove .html from url
Url will be **www.mydomainname.com/shop**

Please give me any idea.

Answer (score 8):

**It is so simple.**

Just go to

> admin > System > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Search Engine Optimizations

Then make **Product URL Suffix** and **Category URL Suffix** is blank and click on save Config

**Clear Cache and do reindexing**

Comment: Hello amit i have follow above instruction but i have found this statement every time {One or more of the Indexes are not up to date: Catalog URL Rewrites. Click here to go to Index Management and rebuild required indexes.}

Comment: please provide a way to solve it. right now i am in this loaction in admin area {mydomainname.com/index.php/admin/process/list/key/62eba4d619613449d1982f8e346cd0c3/

Comment: have u tried with comand line indexing

Comment: http://inchoo.net/magento/executing-magento-indexer-from-shell/

Answer (score 3):

You can change it from the admin panel, on:

System > Configuration > Catalog > Search Engine Optimizations

Set empty the following fields:

Product URL Suffix
Category URL Suffix

If the store has been indexed you should redirect the old URLs to the new ones, you can do it with a redirect rule on your htacces, something like:

```
RewriteRule ^index.php/?(.*).html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 3):

Go to `System -> Configuration -> Catalog`

Go to Catalog and Expand the Search Engine Optimization tab.

Remove the `.html` text from Category URL Suffix.

It will remove `.html` from all category page.

> If you want to remove `.html` from product page also then remove it from `Product URL Suffix` also.

Go to `system -> index management` and reindex all.

Comment: I have already done this instruction. But my issue till now remaining

Comment: @HusainAhmed, truncate "core_url_rewrite" table from Database and do reindex. and clear all cache. It will resolve your issue

Answer (score 1):

Go to admin System -> Configuration -> Catalog.

Go to Catalog and Expand the Search Engine Optimization tab. Remove the **“.html”** text from both the input fields. **Product URL Suffix** and **Category URL Suffix**.

Comment: I have already done this instruction. But my issue till now remaining

Comment: have you reindex and cleared cahce?