# Magento2: How to remove .html from product url of category

Tags: magento2

I need to remove .html from product url
Eg: 
Product url https://www.test.com/category.html/product.html to https://www.test.com/category/product.html

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove .html from Magento url](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/158745/how-to-remove-html-from-magento-url)

Comment: I got it answer after index